# Expected Identifier Error when implementing leadbolt ads

Tags: ios, xcode, ads, leadbolt

I am currently implementing LeadBolt interstitial ads into my iOS app. However, at the end of this line:

```
[[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleModuleFail) name:@"onModuleFailed" object:@"AppFireworksNotification"]];
```

I am getting an "expected identifier" error. Please advise on how this can be resolved.

```
-(void)loadDisplayAd
{
   LeadboltOverlay *interstitial = [LeadboltOverlay createAdWithSectionid:@"YOUR_LB_INTERSTITIAL_ID" view:self.view];
   [interstitial loadAd];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {

    LeadboltOverlay *audioad = [LeadboltOverlay createAdWithSectionid:@"YOUR_LB_AUDIO_ID" view:self.view];
    [audioad loadAudioAd];
    // [AppTracker setLandscapeMode:YES]; // Un-comment for Landscape mode
    [[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleModuleFail) name:@"onModuleFailed" object:@"AppFireworksNotification"]];
    [AppTracker startSession:@"APPFIREWORKS_API_KEY" view:self.view];


    [self loadDisplayAd];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra set of brackets. Replace this:

```
[[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleModuleFail) name:@"onModuleFailed" object:@"AppFireworksNotification"]];
```

With this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleModuleFail) name:@"onModuleFailed" object:@"AppFireworksNotification"];
```

Comment: That worked... Although,when I run my app and go to the viewDidLoad where this ad is the app crashes and it says in green: thread 1: signal SIGABRT... any ideaa what that is? sorry, new to xcode

Comment: You should add an [exception breakpoint](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17802723/1145804), that will give you more info. That question should be posted separately though since it's not the same question as this. Please accept my answer if you can.

Comment: Just click the checkmark under the up/down arrows next to the answer. It helps to identify the correct answer to future developers who may have the same problem.